# Python: 'No module named []' in a weird situation

Tags: python, import, module

I'm getting a 'No module named []' in a situation that I don't understand. I can bruteforce it with an overly conservative PYTHONPATH, but I'd like to understand what's really going on.

My directory structure:

```
/project
    main.py
    /subfolder
        subcomponent1.py
        subcomponent2.py
```

In main.py, there's the following import:

```
from subfolder import subcomponent1
```

and then in subcomponent1.py, there's the following import:

```
import subcomponent2
```

And when I run main.py, I get 'No module named subcomponent2'. If main.py can see subcomponent1.py fine and successfully run it to encounter the 'import subcomponent2' statement, how can it not see subcomponent2.py in the same directory as subcomponent1.py?

If I just run subcomponent1.py (which has its own main function and can be run independently), it has no problem seeing subcomponent2.

I'm really perplexed by this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does your /subfolder directory have an __init__.py file? If not, can you add an empty __init__.py file and try again?

Comment: I do have an init.py file, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In subcomponent1.py, you should include

```
from subfolder import subcomponent2
```

as well because python importing always starts at the root of the directory.

Comment: Hmm that worked, although it seems really counter-intuitive to me. So is it Python best-practice to always include the directory for parallel files in the same directory in case they're later called by something not in the same directory?

Comment: It depends where you run the file from. If you run main.py from the project directory as `python main.py`, then the above works. You can also try: `import .subfolder2` in your subcomponent1.py file. The dot lets python know that the module you are looking for is in the current directory (assuming you are using python3+)

Comment: You can read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules I'm not an official person on this matter.